# Backend Internal error: Exception during psi2ir in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am getting this error during compilation or code generation, I have set the Jetpack Compose dependencies and working on it, I have made some compose components and previews are visible but during compilation I am getting this issue.

I am using Android Studio ArticFox

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during psi2ir
File being compiled: (154,13) in /Users/vipulthawre/AndroidStudioProjects/tbappCompose/base-question-module/src/main/java/com/testbook/tbapp/base_question/MamcqPracticeHtml.kt

The root cause java.lang.StackOverflowError was thrown at: java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
null: KtBinaryExpression:

"<style type=\"text/css\"> \n" + 
"    body {\n" + 
"        color: #1E2022;\n" + 
"        margin: 0px;\n" + 
"    }\n" + 
"\n" + 
"
```

and the script is in that file as follows

```
private fun getStyle(): String {
    val styleCss =
            "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n" + "    body {\n" + "        color: #1E2022;\n" + "        margin: 0px;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .question {\n" + "        padding: 16px;\n" + "        font-size: 16px;\n" + "        border-bottom: 1px solid " + dividerColor + ";\n" + "        background: #FFFFFF;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .option {\n" + "        padding: 0;\n" + "        margin-left:8px; margin-right:8px;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .option li {\n" + "        box-sizing: border-box;\n" + "        font-size: 16px;\n" + "        width: calc(100% - 38px);\n" + "        display: table;\n" + "        border: 1px solid transparent;\n" + "        border-bottom-color: " + dividerColor + ";\n" + "        list-style: none;\n" + "        padding: 18px;\n" + "        margin-top: 5px;\n" + "        margin-bottom: 5px;\n" + "        border-radius: 2px;\n" + "        background: #FFFFFF;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .view-solution-div {\n" + "        box-sizing: border-box;\n" + "        font-size: 16px;\n" + "        width: 100%;\n" + "        display: table;\n" + "        border: 1px solid transparent;\n" + "        border-bottom: 1px solid " + dividerColor + ";\n" + "        list-style: none;\n" + "        padding: 18px;\n" + "        border-radius: 2px;\n" + "        background: #FFFFFF;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .solution {\n" + "        position: relative;\n" + "        padding: 16px;\n" + "        border-bottom: 1px solid " + dividerColor + ";\n" + "        border-radius: 3px;\n" + "        background: #FFFFFF;\n" + "        overflow: hidden;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .solution_overlay {\n" + "        position: absolute;\n" + "        left: 0;\n" + "        right: 0;\n" + "        top: 0;\n" + "        bottom: 0;\n" + "        margin: auto;\n" + "        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);\n" + "        text-align: center;\n" + "        font-weight: bold;\n" + "        color: #222;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .solution_overlay p {\n" + "        position: absolute;\n" + "        padding: 16px;\n" + "        left: 0;\n" + "        right: 0;\n" + "        margin: 0;\n" + "        top: 50% !important;\n" + "        -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);\n" + "        transform: translate(0, -50%);\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    #solution {\n" + "        border-bottom: 1px solid " + dividerColor + ";\n" + "        position: relative;\n" + "        padding: 8px;\n" + "        background: #FFFFFF;\n" + "        overflow: hidden;\n" + "        margin-top: 16px;\n" + "        margin-bottom:20px;" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .blurred {\n" + "        text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);\n" + "        color: transparent;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .numerical {\n" + "        width: 100%;\n" + "        padding-top: 30px;\n" + "        padding-bottom: 30px;\n" + "        margin-bottom: 70px;\n" + "        margin-top: 50px;\n" + "        border-bottom: 1px solid " + dividerColor + ";\n" + "        border-radius: 1px;\n" + "        background: #FFFFFF;\n" + "        display: table;\n" + "        box-sizing: border-box;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    #ans_div {\n" + "        padding-left: 20px !important;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .numerical input {\n" + "        background: #fff;\n" + "        border-bottom: 1px solid #A9A9A9;\n" + "        font-style: normal !important;\n" + "        outline: none !important;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .numerical button {\n" + "        background: #fff;\n" + "        border: 0px !important;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .numerical input:active, .numerical input:focus {\n" + "        border-bottom: 2px solid #1FBAD6 !important;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .wrongNumerical {\n" + "        background: #ffe5e5 !important;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .correctNumerical {\n" + "        background: #e5ffe5 !important;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .correctOption {\n" + "        border-radius: 1px!important;\n" + "        background: rgba(139, 213, 139, 0.25)!important;\n" + "        border: 1px solid rgba(110, 194, 110, 0.85)!important;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .correctNumerical {\n" + "        border-radius: 1px;\n" + "        background: rgba(139, 213, 139, 0.25);\n" + "        border: 1px solid rgba(110, 194, 110, 0.85);\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .markedOption {\n" + "        border-radius: 1px !important;\n" + "        background: rgba(170, 216, 225, 0.25) !important;\n" + "        border: 1px solid rgba(42, 160, 182, 0.85) !important;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .wrongOption {\n" + "        border-radius: 1px!important;\n" + "        background: rgba(254, 159, 159, 0.25)!important;\n" + "        border: 1px solid rgba(231, 67, 67, 0.85)!important;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    input[placeholder] {\n" + "        font-style: italic;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {\n" + "        -webkit-appearance: none;\n" + "        margin: 0;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    p {\n" + "        margin: 0;\n" + "        padding: 0;\n" + "        line-height: 23px;\n" + "        font-family: 'roboto';\n" + "        font-size: 16px;\n" + "        color: #1E2022 !important;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    span {\n" + "        margin: 0;\n" + "        padding: 0;\n" + "        line-height: 23px;\n" + "        font-family: 'roboto';\n" + "        font-size: 16px;\n" + "        color: #1E2022 !important;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    img {\n" + "        max-width: 100% !important;\n" + "        height: auto !important;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .MathJax_SVG svg > g, .MathJax_SVG_Display svg > g {\n" + "        fill: #1E2022 !important;\n" + "        stroke: #1E2022 !important\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .switch {\n" + "        position: relative;\n" + "        display: inline-block;\n" + "        width: 35px;\n" + "        height: 14px;\n" + "        vertical-align: middle;\n" + "        margin-left: 10px;\n" + "        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .switch input {\n" + "        display: none;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .slider {\n" + "        position: absolute;\n" + "        cursor: pointer;\n" + "        top: 0;\n" + "        left: 0;\n" + "        right: 0;\n" + "        bottom: 0;\n" + "        background-color: rgba(17, 171, 213, 0.13);\n" + "        -webkit-transition: .2s;\n" + "        transition: .2s;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .slider:before {\n" + "        position: absolute;\n" + "        content: \"\";\n" + "        height: 20px;\n" + "        width: 20px;\n" + "        left: -1px;\n" + "        bottom: -3px;\n" + "        background-color: #A5A8B6;\n" + "        -webkit-transition: .2s;\n" + "        transition: .2s;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    input:focus + .slider {\n" + "        box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    input:checked + .slider:before {\n" + "        -webkit-transform: translateX(15px);\n" + "        transform: translateX(15px);\n" + "        background-color: #1EB6D2;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    /* Rounded sliders */\n" + "    .slider.round {\n" + "        border-radius: 34px;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .slider.round:before {\n" + "        border-radius: 50%;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .missedOption {\n" + "        border-radius: 1px!important;\n" + "        background: rgba(125, 193, 125, 0.1)!important;\n" + "        border: 1.5px dashed rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.85)!important;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .markedOption {\n" + "        border-radius: 1px !important;\n" + "        background: rgba(170, 216, 225, 0.25) !important;\n" + "        border: 1px solid rgba(42, 160, 182, 0.85) !important;\n" + "    }\n" + "\n" + "    .btn {\n" + "        display: inline-block;\n" + "        margin: 8px;\n" + "        font-weight: 400;\n" + "        text-align: center;\n" + "        vertical-align: middle;\n" + "        touch-action: manipulation;\n" + "        cursor: pointer;\n" + "        border: 1px solid #000000;\n" + "        white-space: nowrap;\n" + "        padding: 6px 12px;\n" + "        font-size: 14px;\n" + "        line-height: 1.42857143;\n" + "        border-radius: 0;\n" + "        -webkit-user-select: none;\n" + "        -moz-user-select: none;\n" + "        -ms-user-select: none;\n" + "        user-select: none;\n" + "    }\n" + "    .btn-primary {\n" + "        border: 1px solid transparent;\n" + "        color: #fff;\n" + "        background-color: #1fbad6;\n" + "        border-color: #1fbad6;\n" + "        border-radius: 4px;\n" + "        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.2)\n" + "    }" + "    .multi-info {\n" + "        color: #CDCDCD!important;\n" + "        font-size: 14px!important;\n" + "    }" + "    .missed-answer-text {\n" + "       position: absolute;\n" + "       bottom:0;\n" + "       right:0;\n" + "       font-size: 8px;\n" + "       background-color: #20b24e;\n" + "       color: white!important;        \n" + "       padding-top: 0px;\n" + "       padding-bottom: 0px;\n" + "       line-height: 16px;\n" + "       padding-left: 10px;        \n" + "       padding-right: 10px;    \n" + "   }    \n" + "   .icon-img{\n" + "       position: relative;\n" + "       float: right;\n" + "       clear: both;\n" +
//                "       top:-10px;\n" +
                "   }" + "\n" + "    </style>"

        return styleCss
}
```

Image:

[image]

my module.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        // Enables Jetpack Compose for this module

        compose true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion = "1.5.10"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.0-beta09"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":resource-module")
    implementation project(":constants-module")
    implementation project(":prefs-module")

    implementation project(":network-module")

    implementation project(path: ':models-module')
    implementation project(":base-ui-module")

    api 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    api("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-beta09")
    // Tooling support (Previews, etc.)
    api("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta09")
    // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
    api("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.0.0-beta09")
    // Material Design
    api("androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-beta09")
    // Material design icons
    api("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:1.0.0-beta09")
    api("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.0.0-beta09")
    // Integration with observables
    api("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta09")
    api("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:1.0.0-beta09")
    api("androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.0.0-beta09")

    api 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-beta02'
    // UI Tests
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.0-beta09")
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issues but I don't think it's related to Jetpack Compose. As soon as I updated my Kotlin compiler to 1.5.20, this problem started happening to my project as well. Everything works ok with 1.4.32.

I'm not using Jetpack Compose on my project and I'm using the stable release of Android Studio (4.2.2)

Answer (score 4):

This issue is occurring cause the styleCss string is a collection of more than 100+ small strings which are being appended together to create a single string but due to the reduction of stack size of Kotlin from version 1.5.0, it is giving a `Stackoverflow` Error. This issue can be solved by using [multiLineStringLiteral of Kotlin](https://realkotlin.com/tutorials/2018-06-26-multiline-string-literals-in-kotlin/) something like this.

```
val styleCss =
            """<style type=\"text/css\">
        body {
            color: #1E2022;
            margin: 0px;
        }"""
```

I have solved the above issue using this way. You can read more about this [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49453#focus=Comments-27-5350497.0-0).

Answer (score 3):

I was having same issue Invalidate Caches / Restart in Android Studio worked for me

Answer (score 3):

**Build > Clean Project** fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

For me, the real issue was hidden in the top level build error:

[image]

Click that and it should reveal a lengthier error message with a stack trace.

Comment: any resolution?

Answer (score 1):

This occurred to my build after updating Kotlin version from 1.5.31 to 1.6.0. Reverting back the build finished

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was kodein import issue.

For this `override val kodein by kodein()`

We need to import `import org.kodein.di.android.x.kodein`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like import issue

```
import org.kodein.di.KodeinAware
import org.kodein.di.android.kodein
```